# jqGrid binding event in gridComplete function

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I'm using jqgrid in my ASP.NET MVC project. I'm trying to bind click event in gridComplete function. Then I want to detect if cell, that was clicked is editable or not. So far I've got this:

```
    gridComplete: function () {
                var ids = jQuery("#resources").jqGrid('getDataIDs');
                for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
                    var cl = ids[i];
                    jQuery('#resources').jqGrid('editRow', cl);
                }
                $("#resources td").click(function(e) {
                    ...//here I want to check if clicked cell is editable
                });

     }
```

as you can see I'm making rows ready for edit right after loading a grid. this refers only to columns with attribute editable=true.

UPDATE:

The solution was very simple:

```
    $("#resources td").click(function(e) {
                    var sClassName = e.target.className;
                    if (sClassName == "editable") {
                        //editable cell is clicked
                    }
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't full understand your requirements. What additional actions you want to do on click of the "editable" or "non-editable" cell?

Nevertheless I would recommend you to use [onCellSelect](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aevents) callback handler instead of binding `click` event to every cell of the grid. For understanding every binding required some resources of the web browser. Instead of binding events to cells you can do only *one* bind to any parent element of cell like the `<table>` element (the grid itself). Because of the mechanism known as [event flow](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-flow), *event propagation* or *event bubbling* the unhandled events will be tried be handled by the same event handler of the parent element or the parent of the parent and so on. The event handler receive [Event object](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/) which [target](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/) property helps to detect which element was originally clicked.

So you can use the code like

```
onCellSelect: function (rowid, iCol, cellcontent, e) {
    var colModel = $(this).jqGrid('getGridParam', 'colModel');
    if ($.isArray(colModel) && !colModel[iCol].editable) {
        // non-editable cell is clicked 
    }
}
```

or this

```
onCellSelect: function (rowid, iCol, cellcontent, e) {
    if (!this.p.colModel[iCol].editable) {
        // non-editable cell is clicked 
    }
}
```

to detect whether the currently clicked cell was non-editable.

Comment: I tried with onCellSelect event, but it's fired only for non-editalble cells. My requirment is that I have to fade in or fade out some sections on my page depending on edeitable/non-editable cell is clicked.

Comment: @maciek: Sorry, but I don't understand what you mean. Because I see that you solved the problem yourself in some way it's probably not important to clear now your exact requirements.